# ML.NET - Image classification program always returns a wrong prediction

Tags: ml.net

I am trying to create an image classification program using the ML.NET library. I am following the steps described in the Microsoft tutorial below.

I loaded 100 red images and 100 blue images. The training phase seems to be working great as it was able to make predictions with 100% accuracy. The problem happens when using the model; it always returns the wrong prediction and the score is always 0. What could cause that issue?

[ML.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/image-classification-api-transfer-learning)

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem. The issue was that my input data had the image path but a byte array of the image was also needed.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. I would also recommend when experimenting to try out Model Builder. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/image-classification-model-builder